# I have to filter specific columns with blank cells and remove those rows in a csv file using Python

Tags: python, csv

I have columns C1,...C10. And I have to filter columns C1 and C5 separately check if these contains blank cells. If blanks are there i will have to remove those rows. Can anybody help me writing a code.
Thank You

Tried this

```
import csv
import sys

input_file_name=r"input file name"
output_file=r"output file name"


with open(input_file_name) as csv_file:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter='|')
    GLOBAL_C1 = 0
    GLOBAL_C5 = 0
    for idx, row in enumerate(csv_reader):
        if idx == 0:
            for col_idx,col_name in enumerate(row):
                if col_name == "C1":
                    GLOBAL_C1 = col_idx
                    continue
                if col_name == "C5":
                    GLOBAL_C5 = col_idx
                    break
        if row[GLOBAL_C1] == '':
            continue
        if row[GLOBAL_C5] == '':
            continue
        else:
            csvfile = open(output_file, 'a', newline='')
            writer = csv.writer(csvfile,delimiter='|')
            writer.writerow(row)
```

Comment: What have you tried and why didn't it work? "

Comment: `df[df.C1!= '']` can filter empty cells for C1. please share what you have tried by now to be in same page

Comment: I have tried a code

Comment: @varshashetty Then provide us with that code and explain why that code did not work. Then we can help you to fix that code.

Comment: I have tried a code by writing only the non blank cells to a different sheet, which didn't work.

Comment: @varshashetty Please update your question and add that code. Then explain why that didn't work, not only "It didn't work". Stack Overflow is not a place where people do your work and write code for you, it's a place where people help you writing your own code.

Comment: I am trying to paste the code. First time using this platform, getting to know.

Comment: @varshashetty I posted a code that may fit to your problem

Answer (score 3):

You can use below code:

Table(CSV) that i used:

```
   C12  C22  C32
0  NaN  C23  NaN
1  NaN  C24  C34
2  C15  NaN  C35
3  C16  NaN  C36
4  C17  C27  C37
5  C18  C28  C38
6  C19  C29  C39
```

Code:

```
import pandas as pd 
df=pd.read_csv('1.csv')  
print(df)
df1 = df.dropna()
print(df1)
```

Output:

```
   C12  C22  C32
4  C17  C27  C37
5  C18  C28  C38
6  C19  C29  C39
```